# Convert Mac Keyboard Layout to a Windows (7) One

Tags: windows, osx, keyboard-layout

I have created a very extensive custom keyboard layout using [Ukelele](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/14495/ukelele) for my Mac. It contains hundreds of different characters and dozens of (multi-level) dead keys.

Now I would like to have this same keyboard layout on my Windows 7 computer. I know there are editors for keyboard layouts on Windows out there, but it would be extremely tedious to put every character in there again by hand. Let alone keeping the two layouts the same if I decide to modify one.

**Is there a program that will allow me to convert the .keyboard layout to the designated Windows layout, while retaining all dead keys and modifier states** (I'm only using regular/alt/shift/alt+shift here)?

The physical keyboard upon which the layout is based is contained in the physical keyboard for my Windows computer (it has a numeric pad and home/end and so on keys in addition, and lacks the Fn key, but I don't use that one in my layout).